# How to override the an inherent property when using its related method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, properties, overriding

```
class foo:

   @property
   def nums(self):
       return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

   def gt(self, x):
       return [num for num in self.nums if num > x] 

class bar(foo):

    @property
    def nums(self):
        return super().gt(3)

f = foo()
b = bar()

print(f.nums)
print(b.nums)
```

The above code will have infinite recursion.

The desired result is to print `[4, 5]` when I call `b.nums`.  How may I have the desired result? Thank you.

Comment: Change `super()` with `foo()` or rename `nums` inside `bar` with another name, or it will create a recursion.

Comment: You simply do have a logical recursion. How can a value be returned from `nums` when it gets its value from `gt` which calculates its value from `nums` which get its value from `gt`…?

Comment: @Carlo Zanocco excellent, mind to explain more? but such that it is creating another `foo()` in `bar`..? anyway to avoid that?

Comment: @ChrisLAM Take a look to the option 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is non-logical by default.
The function `nums` in class `bar` overrides the function `nums` in class `foo` - therefore when you call the `self.nums` in list-comprehension of `gt` function - the actual `nums` invoked is the overrided one in `bar`.

not sure what are your constraints, but just not override will do the work:

```
class foo:

   @property
   def nums(self):
       return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

   def gt(self, x):
       return [num for num in self.nums if num > x] 

class bar(foo):

    @property
    def nums2(self):
        return super().gt(3)

f = foo()
b = bar()

print(f.nums)
print(b.nums2)
```

other option is to make the `nums` a member and return it from `nums`, like here:

```
class foo:
    nums_member = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    @property
    def nums(self):
       return self.nums_member

    def gt(self, x):
       return [num for num in self.nums_member if num > x] 

class bar(foo):

    @property
    def nums(self):
        return super().gt(3)

f = foo()
b = bar()

print(f.nums)
print(b.nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a recursion because the duplicate `nums`. You have two ways to solve it:

- Rename the `nums` inside the `bar` class with another name
- Don't use `super()` but specify the class name `foo()`

### Option 1

```
class foo:
    @property
    def nums(self):
       return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    def gt(self, x):
       return [num for num in self.nums if num > x] 

class bar(foo):
    @property
    def diffrent_nums(self):
        return super().gt(3)

f = foo()
b = bar()

print(f.nums)
print(b.diffrent_nums)
```

Having the duplicate property name `nums` generate the recursion, because you call:

`print(b.nums)` --> `return super().gt(3)` --> `return [num for num in self.nums if num > x]`  --> `return super().gt(3)` --> ....

In your for loop you call `self.nums` that is the `bar().nums` that calls again the for that calls the nums again and again

### Option 2

```
class foo:
    @property
    def nums(self):
       return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    def gt(self, x):
       return [num for num in self.nums if num > x] 

class bar(foo):
    @property
    def nums(self):
        return foo().gt(3)

f = foo()
b = bar()

print(f.nums)
print(b.nums)
```

This will generate a new instance of the class `foo`.

Comment: I would not consider option 2 to be sensible. If the class requires arguments for instantiation, you're pretty screwed.